# Return the output of html id to php string

Tags: javascript, php, html

I like to make an advertisement base on the visitor state/region. And also to display language based on visitor country.

I am trying to get data from this website and works well in ( only displaying the output) :

```
jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    // example where I update content on the page.
    jQuery('#city').html(location.city);
    jQuery('#region-code').html(location.region_code);
    jQuery('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
    jQuery('#areacode').html(location.areacode);
    jQuery('#ip').html(location.ip);
    jQuery('#zipcode').html(location.zipcode);
    jQuery('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
    jQuery('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
    jQuery('#country-name').html(location.country_name);
    jQuery('#country-code').html(location.country_code);
  }
} );
```

of course this will give the visitor state data on browser :

```
<div id="region-name"></div>
```

Problems :

1. How can I get the id output save in php string.
2. I want to ave it to database using PDO prepare statement.

I have tried to save it by doing:

```
$state='<div id="region-name"></div>';
$pages->testsavestate($state); // save to database PDO

public function testsavestate($state) {

        $ses_id = session_id(); 
        $country='mycountry';

        $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `visitors`(`session`, `country`, `state`) VALUES 
        (?,?,?)");

        $query->bindValue(1, $ses_id);
        $query->bindValue(2, $country);
        $query->bindValue(3, $state);

        try{
            $query->execute();

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

It didn't save the state result, but only the above the tag.

Thanks

Comment: you have to make an ajax call to post the values. php can't read the current state of the client.

Comment: Additionally if you're doing this with PHP anyway you might as well use CURL to make the request rather than in JS. Pass `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` into the API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for that data to travel from your first AJAX call to get location values. You can also call another ajax on top of that to your PHP processing. Consider this example:

```
jQuery.ajax( { 
    url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
        jQuery('#city').html(location.city);
        jQuery('#region-code').html(location.region_code);
        jQuery('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
        jQuery('#areacode').html(location.areacode);
        jQuery('#ip').html(location.ip);
        jQuery('#zipcode').html(location.zipcode);
        jQuery('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
        jQuery('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
        jQuery('#country-name').html(location.country_name);
        jQuery('#country-code').html(location.country_code);
        // after your .html() below

        // after your successful ajax outside, call your php file
        var country = location.country_name;
        var state = location.region_name;
        // call your php file
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'index.php', // <-- name of the php file that will handle such request 
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { country: country, state: state },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Then on your php file, process the values

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {

    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $ses_id = session_id();
    $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `visitors`(`session`, `country`, `state`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $query->bindValue(1, $ses_id);
    $query->bindValue(2, $country);
    $query->bindValue(3, $state);
    try {
        $query->execute();
        if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo "Save complete!";
            exit;
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    } 
}
```